# max-width has no effect on pre tag?

Tags: html, css

Demo `demo.html` and `style.css`:

```css
div.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "left main right";
  grid-template-columns: 19em auto 19em;
}

div.left {
  grid-area: left;
  background-color: beige;
}

div.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: beige;
}

div.main {
  grid-area: main;
}

pre {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
<div class="left">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo velit, vitae perferendis commodi enim autem architecto optio laboriosam omnis eius dolorum similique rem, asperiores exercitationem in beatae, harum natus reiciendis.</p>
  <pre>
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{frame}
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node at (3.1415,1) {I'm here};
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node at (current page.center) {I'm the centre of the frame!};
\end{frame}
  </pre>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Since I have set `max-width` for `pre`, why is there still a scroll bar in the bottom of the web page? If I comment out the `pre` tag, everything is fine.

I want to know how to modify the css for `pre` such that the web page width is the same as the screen width.

Comment: min-width:0 to .main

Comment: Amazing! I'm looking for such a code line for a long time. Thank you@TemaniAfif